# Normalization of a Wave-function in spherical co-ordinates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, integration, normalization

**So I have been provided with the following wave-function**

$ψ(x, y, z) = N(x + y + z)e^\frac{
−r^
2}{α^2}$

**I am trying to convert it to spherical co-ordinates and to find the Normalization constant** $N$

**My Knowledge**: $x=r\sin\theta \cos\phi$, $y=r\sin\theta \sin\phi$, $z=r\cos\theta$

**Applying this to the wave-function**:

$ψ(r,\theta, \phi) = N(r\sin\theta \cos\phi + r\sin\theta \sin\phi + r\cos\theta)e^\frac{
−r^
2}{α^2}$

**My issue**: I'm stuck here, to calculate the normalization constant do I take:

**(1)**:$$\iiint |N(r\sin\theta \cos\phi + r\sin\theta \sin\phi + r\cos\theta)e^\frac{
−r^
2}{α^2}|^2\,r^2dr d\theta d\phi $$

or **(2)** : $$\psi(r, \theta, \phi) = R(r)Y(\theta, \phi)$$ then the normalization condition becomes $$\int |\psi|^2 r^2 \sin \theta dr d \theta d \phi = \int |R|^2 r^2 dr \int |Y|^2 \sin \theta d \theta d \phi = 1$$

I am very familiar with integration however this integral is causing me lots of issues so I am wondering is there a better method of approaching this, perhaps seperating the integral more?

Any help is appreciated. Apologies in advance if there are formatting issues, I am trying to familiarize myslef with this site. Thanks.

Comment: Your two methods are the same if $\psi(r,\theta,\phi)=R(r)Y(\theta,\phi)$

$$\iiint|\psi(r,\theta,\phi)|^2r^2\,\text dr\,\text d\theta\,\text d\phi=\iiint|R(r)Y(\theta,\phi)|^2r^2\,\text dr\,\text d\theta\,\text d\phi=\int|R(r)|^2r^2\,\text dr\iint|Y(\theta,\phi)|^2\,\text d\theta\,\text d\phi$$

Comment: Ok thanks. To confirm, that is the correct way of calculating the normalization constant N?

Comment: Yes, $\iiint|\psi|^2\,\text dV=1$

Comment: $(x+y+z)$ is not spherically symmetric, so it can't be part of an $R(r)$, nor is it a single spherical harmonic.

Comment: If it cannot be a part of $R(r)$ since it is not spherically symmetric is it still possible to  calculate the probabilities of physical measurements of angular momentum operators of a system characterised by this wave-function?

Comment: Given the form of $\psi$, it may be simpler to do the integration in cartesian coordinates (unless the boundaries are very awkward).

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez I am asked to do it in spherical co-ordinates. I can't seem to figure out the integration despite a number of attempts at substitution methods. This should be trivial which makes it more frustrating.

Comment: In your first integral you are missing a $\sin\theta$ factor in the d$V$ section. d$V=r^2\sin\theta\mathrm{d}r~\mathrm{d}\theta~\mathrm{d}\phi.$

Comment: @BillN Oops. I did the same thing in my comment :)

Comment: @JEB I think the OP means to just separate based on variable dependence, not specifically using spherical harmonics. The wave function can be written as a product of a function of $r$ and a function of $\theta$ and $\phi$

Comment: If $\langle l,m|z| l',m'\rangle$ and  $\langle l,m|x\pm iy| l',m'\rangle$ have known values, you can convert the integral into a sum over spherical harmonics, maybe. Note that those are just the expectations of the $Y_{l=1}^m$'s.

Answer (score 0):

If you are obliged to do the integral in spherical coordinates, then take your expression 1 (remembering to include a factor of $\sin \theta$ in the integrand as Bill N remarked). Now expand $\psi^2$. You will obtain many products of trigonometric functions, but these can all be solved by using the standard tricks. After doing the $\theta$ and $\phi$ integrations, you'll be left with the integral of $\int r^4 e^{-r^2/a^2} dr$. If you are doing the integral over all space, as I suspect, then this is a standard result (the 4-th moment of a Gaussian). If you carefully keep track of all the terms, this will give you the final result.

Comment: Thanks for the shout out!